# TextViews and Intents problems

Tags: java, android, xml

I have 40 textviews but I want to know which one was pressed so that it takes me to the desired Intent. How do I implement this ?

Comment: How did you manage 40 textViews? If you use a ListView or RecyclerView, you can manage all the clicks with the position of the view that's clicked

Answer (score 2):

Implement onClickListener for all the TextViews. And handle the clicks according to TextView IDs in your listener. Its same as you handle onClick for a single textView.

In your listener use:

```
  public void onClick(View view) {
            switch(view.getId()) {
                case R.id.textView1:
                    break;
                case R.id.textView2:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is  there a way i can use a Switch() to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an OnClickListener for all the views can be cumersome. The best way is probably a better way of laying these textView out. Probably a ListView or some implementation of RecyclerView.
But just as an answer to your question, make your class implement View.OnClickListener and check the id of the clicked View in the onClick method.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.textView1:
                // code here
                break;
            case R.id.textView2:
                //code here
                break;
        }
    }
}
```